# Datamodel in biblatex, hashname and biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm trying to create my own biblatex datamodel to describe medieval manuscripts.

My .dbx file is actually

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{manuscript}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[manuscript]{Datation}
```

My bib file has this content:

```
@manuscript{P1470,
    Library={BNF},
    Address={Paris},
    Datation={\textsc{viii}\textsuperscript{e} s.}
}
```

I have no author or like field, because my manuscript is anonymous.

And I call it by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[datamodel=manuscript,bibstyle=verbose,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{titi.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The xelatex runs perfectly. But in my first run of biber (and only at my first run), I obtained these warning.

Use of uninitialized value in hash element at

```
/var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 61.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 62.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 61.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 62.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 60.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 61.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/0g/vh5y8yv93js6v76gmjpnt4mr0000gr/T/par-6d616965756c/cache-1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 62.
```

Is it normal ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem: don't load `xunicode` (it's already loaded by `fontspec`).

Comment: I don't get an error with biber 1.7 + 1.8. Did you try to delete the cache folder `par-6d616965756c`?

Comment: @egreg: thanks, I always forget, because in the first example I read it was written.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have deleted the full folder. The error didn't reappar...

Comment: I opened a new question, in relation with this, but quite ≠ and more problematic. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146886/declaredatamodelentryfields-make-biber-doesnt-work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that was solved by deleting a temporary (cache) folder created by Biber.