# \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields : make biber does'nt work

Tags: biblatex, biber

that is a a completion of my question [Datamodel in biblatex, hashname and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146862/datamodel-in-biblatex-hashname-and-biber), but I opened a new question because the problem is more problematic.

If any roots want to merge, no problem.

I want to declare new entrytype and new field. I have two solutions:
- use `\DeclareSourceMap` to map entry field (in bib) to another output field (for use with `\printfield{}`
- use new datamap model, to allow to have new fields in my output file.

For some reasons, I prefered to use the second way. So I read biblatex handbook.

I made a `manuscripts.dbx` file, with this content

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{manuscript}
\DeclareDatamodelFields{datation}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{datation}
```

If I read correctly the handbook, it's enough to allow to have `datation` field in my `.bbl` file.

My `.bib` file has this content

```
@manuscript{P1470,
    Library={BNF},
    Address={Paris},
    Datation={\textsc{viii}\textsuperscript{e} s.}
}
```

And my main file has this content

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[datamodel=manuscripts,bibstyle=verbose,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{titi.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
s
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I run xelatex -> no problem

When I run biber -> the bbl output file is empty.

If I comment `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{datation}` -> the bbl output file is not empty, but the field `datation` is not added to the bbl output file.

If I comment `Datation={\textsc{viii}\textsuperscript{e} s.}` -> -> the bbl output file is not empty, but the field `datation` is not added to the bbl output file.

I am on Os X, with Biber 1.8

I I run with latemk, latexmk said "Command for 'biber example' gave return code 6400"

Comment: same problem with .cfg file (indeed, the .bcf file is the same).

Comment: I have mode \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]. It's working. I was persuaded to have done that. It seems I have forgotten. Thanks for your help

Comment: The handbook did'nt say it was mandatory...

Comment: We can remove the comments

Comment: I will fix this in the manual and re-upload 2.8a.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define a new field with `\DeclareDatamodelField` you have to specify the `type` and the `datatype`. In your case you need.

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{datation}
```

The `biblatex` manual does not specify whether such options are required.

Comment: yes, thank. I was persuaded to try it. Indeed not.